# how to run an OOP script to find anagrams

Tags: python-2.7, oop

Totally new to Python OOP.  I am trying to write a code to separate anagrams (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) in a list. The original question from Leetcode is here (https://leetcode.com/problems/anagrams/) For example:

```
strs=["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]
```

It should return:

```
[['eat', 'tea','tan','ate','nat'], ['bat']]
```

I see some discussion codes like (https://leetcode.com/discuss/51190/1-line-ruby-python-for-updated-problem):

```
def groupAnagrams(self, strs):
    groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for s in strs:
        groups[tuple(sorted(s))].append(s)
    return map(sorted, groups.values())
```

Or (https://leetcode.com/discuss/83032/without-sorting-each-string-use-hash-instead-concise-python)

```
def groupAnagrams(self, strs):
    dic = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for str in strs:
        dic[reduce(operator.mul, map(hash, str), 1)].append(str)
    return map(sorted, dic.values())
```

The question is: how can I make this class/function runs to take the list "strs"
as an input and output the desired list?

```
groupAnagrams(self,list1)

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: This question may help you: [What is the purpose of self in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! It does help!

Comment: Solution: call class=>

Answer (score 0):

Call class then we will use the method:

```
class A(object):
     some_method = groupAnagrams

a = A()
print a.some_method(list1)
```

this will give us:

```
[['bat'], ['ate', 'eat', 'tea'], ['nat', 'tan']]
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to use OOP approach here? Why don't you want to define `groupAnagrams` outside the class and leave the `self` parameter?

Comment: I don't think OOP here is necessary, but all the leetcode discussion scripts are in OOP, which kinda annoy me.  Really no need for OOP in such a short script!